# php script appears as a blank screen

Tags: php, web, simple-html-dom, file-manager

I'm trying to run a php script on my website through my file manager but it just shows a white blank screen. I ran a couple of test php scripts on my file manager and runs well. The php script that runs a blank screen has been tested offline with WAMP and works fine, The php script involves connecting to a database which it does, uses simple_html_dom for web scraping and inserting to a database. Can someone please help. Surely if it works offline it should work online no error messages are showing

Comment: Step 1: [Turn on error reporting.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393)

Comment: Add this to the top of your script (or your first calling one) `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 2):

Turn on your error reporting first :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

It might be occurring because you have switched off the error_reporting and the connection is not being successful.
Check if your database connection credentials are correct.

If the problem still exists, refer to this page :

[PHP Blank Screen - Solutions](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/f/white_page_php.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Make your error reporting on by

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, please check php's error log file.

Every page crash is printed there.

Generally, in `php` folders of `WAMP`, `XAMPP`.

For `XAMPP` in `Windows`, the file location is:

```
xampp\php\logs\php_error_log
```